# Magento 2.4.4: Where in admin can I disable Google Pay payment method?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, googlepay

Without me having ever enabled Google Pay as one of the payment methods, it is somehow appearing in the payment page. Could you please help me with the steps to disable it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Google Pay comes with Braintree Payments module which is included in Magento default.

To disable Google Pay, go to Stores > Settings > Configurations.
Navigate to Sales > Payment Methods > Recommended Solutions > Braintree Payments (by GENE Commerce v 4.40) > **GooglePay through Braintree** > set **Enable GooglePay through Braintree** to **No**.

Comment: It has already been set to No.

Comment: I've just known that you are running Stripe payment module. Run this command from the Magento directory: grep -r "Checkout with Google Pay" vendor, you will see the result that indicates which module contain that Google Pay payment method. Then check the system.xml file (`<module dir>/etc/adminhtml/system.xml`) to know the path to disable Google Pay payment method if it exists. If you don't know how to read the config path, copy the file content of system.xml here, I'll take a look.